# How to temporarily disable/reset idle timers?

Tags: idle-timer

I have a package which uses mouse motion, currently the idle timers aren't reset on mouse motion - causing idle timers to run, even when from a user perspective - Emacs is not idle.

How can I stop idle timers from running while my function runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea whether this works, but what happens if you bind `timer-idle-list` to `nil` for the period when you want to prevent an idle timer from going off?

`C-h v` says that it's the list of active timers. If it's `nil` then maybe that will do what you want.

FWIW, I found `timer-idle-list` just by using `C-h v` and typing `timer S-TAB`, with [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) (`S-TAB` does [apropos completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions)). With vanilla Emacs you could just use `M-x apropos RET timer RET` to find it.

---

Otherwise, perhaps you could use `cl-flet` or similar to bind function `current-idle-time` for the duration to a function that just returns `nil`. Or just advise it to do only that.

---

(You could use `cancel-timer` on each of those active idle timers. But I don't think that's what you want to do.)

Comment: This works, even from `track-mouse`, thanks! (updated `scroll-on-drag` package to use this)